# How to read logcat continuously and write into the internal storage file?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Reading logcat continuously and write into the internal storage for this i tried the below code.

```
public class LogCatTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    public AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            //create text file in SDCard
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            Log.e("log cat task...","while...run.get()."+run.get());
            while (run.get()) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                //Log.e("log cat task...","while...out.");
                if (line != null) {
                    Log.e("log cat task...","while....");
                    log.append(line);
                    //publishProgress(log.toString());

                    //to write logcat in text file
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    // Write the string to the file
                    osw.write(log.toString());
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                }
                line = null;
                Thread.sleep(10);
                //Log.e("log cat task...","while...out.");
            }
            //Log.e("log cat task...","ouet....while....");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

once the above code runs,it read the logcat and write into storage but upto some part of the log only it reads.it is not reading the continuos.How to read the logcat continuous?

Comment: Are you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code snippet

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do what you want with the line you just read
            // you're in an infinite loop continuously reading the log,
            // you might want to add some mechanism to break out of it
        }
    }
    catch (IOException  e) {
        fail("failed to get log");
    }
```

Your code is overly complicated and prone to race conditions.  For example, is the logcat -c guaranteed to complete before the logcat -f command. The -f command redirects output to a file, and your logic is also trying to write to that same file; that's very problematic. I've noticed that some of the logcat options such as "-T" doesn't work programmatically. Maybe the "-f" option also has problems.  If you only want to read the log file up to the current time use "logcat -d".